# jquery image map creator IE8 with polygon support

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8, polygon, imagemap

I am looking for a nice jquery plugin that will allow me to create image maps for various images. It must also support the creation of polygon image map shapes.

I have searched all over google and can not find one that will also work in IE8.

I am trying to develop a page that will allow the user to create image maps almost like you would crop an image, by just clicked the areas you want these image maps to be.

I have found some promising ones, but they all fail the IE8 test.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use **iPicture** plugin and its really good.

http://ipicture.justmybit.com/index.php

AND :

dont remember, image mark or mapping its really hard event for old browser. And If you want to use IE8, you need to make&research yourself.

Comment: Hi @MehmetAlp. Thanks for the suggestion. I checked it out and I don't see the support for a creator. Where the user will be able to click and drag his own image maps.